# The html link is rendered on the page but behaves like it doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the navbar made with Bootstrap 3.3.5 and there's the `navbar-brand` anchor element on the very left: here's the [codepen with the code](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/VLoXjp) and here's the [full page view](http://s.codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/debug/VLoXjp).

---

The problem is the following:

this link element `<a href='#' class='navbar-brand'>Symphony</a>` is rendered, I can see it, but its behavior, it's like there's nothing at all. I can't click the link, I can't even select the text inside it.

Any ideas on what the actual problem could be? Is it possible that some CSS somehow implicitly breaks the link or the jQuery code does something wrong?

### Update

I've tried adding this at the end if my stylesheet:

```
a.navbar-brand {
  z-index: 0/-9999/9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: because the link is actually being covered up by the nav bar. You can either fix the nav bar from overlapping that link, or use z-index to make sure the link is the top element.

Comment: @GeorgettePincin I've already tried adding `z-index`  and it didn't help. Please, see the update. Am I doing this somehow wrong?

Comment: position:relative; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdgBLE

Comment: Unless I'm forgetting something, the CSS you posted is invalid.

Comment: z-index only works for positioned elements, you need to figure out what is covering it. Use browsers code inspector to highlight elements and see what's got over your link...

Comment: @Zealander good tip, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below code to `.navbar-brand` and see.

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

It is because this element is overlapping with `.nav-bar`. It will work fine if u increase `z-index` and to do that, we should change the `position: static` of that element to other position value. In your case `position: relative` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Masoom's answer is correct

if you dont want to change css then change position of this
`<a href='#' class='navbar-brand'>Symphony</a>` like this

```
<div class="main-navbar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target="js-navbar-collapse"> 
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>

</div>


<!--"Browse the Store" DROPDOWN -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <a href="https://google.com" class="navbar-brand">Symphony</a>

    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Browse The Store<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">New in Symphony</li>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
              </div>
              <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">View all Instruments <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Violins</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Pianos</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Guitars</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Saxophones</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Support</li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delivery Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ &amp; Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
            <form class="form" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--END "Browse the Store" DROPDOWN -->


  <!-- ========== (LOGIN) JOHN SMITH PROFILE ============= -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">John Smith (₴560000)<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart (₴560000)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- ========== END (LOGIN) JOHN SMITH PROFILE ============= -->


  <!-- ======= START SEARCH ========== -->
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
              <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </span>
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
              <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
        </span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- === END SEARCH === -->
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
```

is overlapping the element with the a-link. You can reorganize the html so that doesn't happen or do this:

```
.nav-brand {
      position:relative;
      z-index:10;
 }
```

[code pen update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdgBLE)